# Can't launch exe file from WSL2

Tags: c++, bash, compilation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I very new to WSL and bash and not that good with C++, so the solution might seem obvious.
I have a bash script that compiles a series of files. It compiles well and I see the .exe file in the explorer window, but when I try to launch the .exe file it doesn't recognise it.

```
jonas@Lenovo-Yoga:/mnt/c/Flatscans/$ bash compilFlatScan.sh
RS232 compiled
commFlatScan compiled
commandes compiled
testFlatScan.exe created
jonas@Lenovo-Yoga:/mnt/c/Flatscans/$ testFlatScan.exe
testFlatScan.exe: command not found
```

It also doesn't launch when I try to execute it by clicking on it.
I can't really find what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this ?

```
 ./testFlatScan.exe
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested, but it says:
unable to open comport : No such file or directory

Comment: Nevermind, it runs. The error comes from the exe file itself, so the execution works but the program has a problem

Comment: Thanks for your help! What does it do differently when using "./" in front of the file name?

Comment: Yes the program starts, thank you. Why does this solve the problem?

Comment: @JonasOffermannMartins without the "./" bash is searching executable in $PATH (you can do `echo $PATH`)... and does not find it. You have to tell bash to search the executable in your current directory, that's the role of "./"

Comment: @JonasOffermannMartins I admit this is surprising at the beginning, but you will quickly get the habit :)

Comment: you can also use `/full/path/to/myProgram.exe` so `./myProgram.exe` is a "short-cut" to using the full path, but assumes you have already used `cd /full/path/to`. Good luck to all.